# Django - login_required not redirecting

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to make a view restricted unless login is done. Was following tuts+plus django unchained tutorial

However login_required decorator somehow is not doing the job. What am I doing wrong?

that part at views.py (login_required has been imported)

```
@login_required
def story(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StoryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = StoryForm()
    return render(request, 'stories/story.html', {'form': form})
```

no changes has been brought in urls.py. So I am hoping for an error where it can't find /login. But that somehow is not happening.

settings.py has LOGIN_URL = "/login/"

Comment: Are you sure it's actually imported? What does your import look like?

Comment: try `@login_required(login_url='/login/')`. and you must add entry in `urls.py`.

Comment: What you see, when access the url, that corresponds to this view with anonymous user? Traceback? 403 forbidden?

Comment: @mevius it looks like 
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

Comment: @stalk I'm actually getting the view with no error whatsoever. And that's exactly what I'm expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is happening. But for some reason in chrome the default story view is opening without redirecting to /login whereas it is working fine in Firefox. I tried clearing the cached images & files in Chrome, but it didn't help.

For now I'll just use Firefox to get through it.

Comment: I've been getting the same issue. Have you resolved this in your case?

Answer (score 4):

Clear the page cookies via chrome DevTool -> Application -> Storage -> Cookies can fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I cleared Chrome chache but it didn't work . Now i am running it on Firefox and its running correctly

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: All the steps which are mentioned above (in question and answers) are correct, but still that code was not working. I had the same problem, my solution was moving to firefox. it resoslved the issue

Comment: This does NOT answer the question. Answering the question means providing a useful approach to solve the problem, and changing browser is not. Why not tell all your users not to use a specific browser? That is not what web app development is about, be a bit realistic, please.

Answer (score 1):

Add an entry in `urls.py` like this:

```
(r'^login/$', 'login_view'),
```

Or you can use remove `LOGIN_URL = "/login/"` from your `settings.py` and use:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
```

> in both case you must add entry to urls.py

Comment: I did try both. Still not working. The story view is opening without redirecting to the login page

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your chrome browser has cleared all of the browsing data, mind that time range choice all time, and then you will solve this problem. I alse encountered this issue, after using Firefox to work well, I got it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by using the logout() function imported the same way as login() and that essentially "cleared" any existence of my already logged in user.

Make a logout view function/url route, run the app and call the url, then you will no longer be able to access the other view functions with the decorator unless logged in once again.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `@login_required` with `@login_required(login_url='login/')` `#'login/'` here you need to call your specific login function name .

Remove your `LOGIN_URL` from settings
and make sure you import this in your views `'from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required'`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can fix this error by just opening your app in Google Chrome's `Incognito Window`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I realized the browser identifies me as a logged-in user because I had logged in before as administrator in the admin page. I logged out of the admin page and the login_required decorator worked correctly.